# Ocelot API Gateway as Outbound Gateway (External Calls)

Tags: .net, gateway, ocelot, outbound

I'm new with Ocelot API Gateway. I see several implementation in .NET Core when we get External Request to the Microservices via the API Gateway (Ocelot).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot

[image]

However, I want to be able to call a Third Parties API from my Microservices, let say my Microservice 2 will call a GET function on the Third Parties API. Like below.

I can't find any C# .NET Core code on Google about what I want to achieve as Outbound Gateway, or Outbound calls.

[image]

Anyone who can help?